# No sql server database connection with localy used IIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, iis, web-config

i am trying to get a database connection through my IIS with an MVC Webproject.
In my Web.conf connection string i use following parameters:

`data source=[Computername]\[DatabaseInstanceName]`

This doesn't work for me.But when change the [Computername] to my IP-Adress it works.

Somebody with an idea what i can do? Because it's annoying to change this everyday in several files.

edit: i am using the IIS 8

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways I verify my connection

1) If you are using visual studio,

a) on the `Data` menu click on `Transact-SQL Editor` and check this dialog

[image]

b) Another trick is I try to create a datasource, follow the dialog box and copy the connection string that Visual Studio generate

c) If look at the Server Explorer and you can find your database there, right click the database and click Properties

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `computername` needs to be accessible to the machine. Currently only the IP address works because nothing is telling the system that `myComputerName` is the machine located at the IP address.

You can either add an entry to your hosts file or to a local DNS server if one is used. If adding to your hosts file (it'll be somewhere like `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`) and you'll need run your text editor as an Administrator. The entry will look something like this:

```
192.168.1.1    JSCWorkstation
```

(obviously change the IP and computer name to your actual values. If the database is running on the same machine as the application you can use the local loopback address (127.0.0.1) as the IP for the entry.

If you are in an environment with a local DNS server you can ask an administrator to add a similar entry in the DNS server.

Once this is done your machine can be found by name rather than by IP address. You can test by opening up a command prompt and typing

`ping myComputername`. If you get a reply, all is well.